# How to run the unregister application on ios 5 device

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one application in Xcode 4.3.I need to run this application on device.Which versions of devices are supported my appliation to run.Iam not register my application.SO please tell me how to do this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're asking is how you can tell what the minimum supported OS for the application you're developing is.

Go to your Project's settings and look at "Deployment Target".

It should look like this:

[image: Deployment Target Settings]

If that isn't the answer you're looking for (now that I see the word "Unregister" in the title), you should edit your question and rephrase it to make it more clear.